# Transfer file to Amazon S3 from web server

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How do I transfer a tarball from my web server (e.g. http://example.com/backup.tar.gz) to an Amazon S3 bucket? Do I have to download it locally and upload it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an SSH access to your server and you can use the amazon tools (e.g. the `ec2-api-tools` package on Ubuntu), then you can upload your tarball directly from your server. However, if you only have FTP access to it, your only choice (afaik) is to download it and upload it from your workstation.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for some sort of command line solution a la wget, but I suppose I can't have it all...

Comment: Well this *is* a command line solution if you use SSH + `ec2-api-tools`.

Comment: I have a (dv) on MediaTemple that I believe is running CentOS, so Ubuntu is not an option :/

Comment: CentOS has `ec2-api-tools`, too : http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing-i386/ec2-api-tools-1.3.36506-1.el5.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much. I confirmed I have Centos, but I'm not sure if I can upload safely via Plesk's application pkg install (screenshot: http://dnho.es/6MSy). However, I installed it on my Mac and am trying to configure it there and figure it out before I put it on my server.

Comment: The Plesk thing seems fine to me. That said, it doesn't hurt to download it to your server with `wget` and install the package with `rpm` directly.

Comment: @Raphink Thanks again. I have it successfully installed on my Mac and it appears I could SSH in if I build a server on the EC2. Would you suggest an Ubuntu instance?

Comment: @ethicka: In general, sure. In particular, that really depends on your needs.

Comment: @ethicka: If you have questions that are more specifically related to server things, you should probably ask on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this services

https://app.mover.io/

or

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-windows-server-backup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [minio client](http://minio.io/#mc) aka mc. Using [mc cp] you can achieve this & alternatively write a cron job for same.

```
$ mc cp backup.tar.gz S3/Mybackupbucket 

mc: minio client
cp : copy command 
backup.tar.gz: File to be copied on S3 bucket
S3: Alias for https://s3.amazonaws.com
Mybackupbucket: your remote bucket on S3
```

hope it helps.